# Use local OTF file for boldface and italic styles

Tags: fonts, bold, italic, minionpro

I recently acquired three OTF files for Minion Pro (minionpro-regular.otf, minionpro-it.otf, and minionpro-semibod.otf). I followed this guide from overleaf on how to use set MinionPro as my main font using the \setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular.otf} command.  I did upload all three files via project.

https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/examples/how-to-use-minion-pro-fonts-with-xelatex/ydsdkcpvsstg

However, this does not cover italic and boldface. Currently, if I try \textbf or \textit, only regular texts show up. Is there a way to set  minionpro-it.otf and minionpro-semibod.otf as the font for italic and boldface respectively?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ItalicFont=` and `BoldFont=` options, such as

```
\setmainfont{MinionPro}[
  UprightFont = *-regular ,
  BoldFont = *-semibold ,
  ItalicFont = *-it ,
  Extension = .otf ]
```

Add `BoldItalicFont =` if you have one, enable any other features you want to use, and tweak to match your filenames.

Comment: Thanks so much! It is working now!